# How to adjust the distance between the labs and axis

Tags: r

```
library(ggplot2)
par(cex.lab=3,
    cex.axis=3,
    mar=c(5,3,2,1)
)
boxplot(Sepal.Length~Species,data=iris,
        boxwex=.7,at=1:3+0.8,boxlwd=2,
        xaxt="n",yaxt="n",lwd=2)
axis(1,at=c(1.8,2.8,3.8),labels=c("SE","VE","VI"),tick = TRUE, line = NA,
     pos = NA, outer = FALSE, font = NA,family="RMN",
     lwd = 2, lwd.ticks = 2, col = "black", col.ticks = "black")
axis(2,line=NA,family="B",
     pos = NA, outer = FALSE, font = NA, lty = "solid")
title(xlab="Species",family="B",
      ylab="Sepal.Length",family="B")
box(lty=1,lwd=2)
```

[image]

I have three questions about this image:

1,How to adjust the distance between the laels and axis, the labels "SE","VE","VI" overlapped the x-axis?

2,How to adjust the distance between the tilte('Species') and labels('VE'..) ?

3,How to save this image after you ploted it, the size of the texts always changed when I change the height and width. So what parameters do you use when you save your images?

I have too many questions, I will appreciate your help very much.

Comment: You're loading `ggplot2`. Are you intending to do this in `ggplot` instead of base R graphics, or is that just a typo?

Comment: yes, i used the ggplot to plot the box, but on bars (horizontal line) upper the box, so, the boxplot produced from base R graphics is more beautiful.